# Why is the file I'm writng to printing gibberish?

Tags: c++

I'm not sure what's happening, but I'm using an ofstream object to write to a file in binary mode.

I am writing a byte to a file, but the file is printing gibberish. It's printing this type of gibberish: `ôß`

I have a class called `ByteOutput` with a function called `inByte` defined as so:

```
void inByte(int byte)
{
    ostreamObj.write(&buffer, byte & 255);
}
```

`&buffer` is a reference to a bit buffer I am using to store a byte of data

In my main, I defined an ofstream obj and opened a file in binary using:

```
obj.open("tester", std::ios::binary);
```

I write a byte of data to the file using a `ByteOutput` object using:

```
writeObj.inByte(1001011);
```

However, when I check the file, it is all hieroglyphics. It does not show the letter K, which has the binary presentation 1001011.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `int a = 1001011`.  what is the value of `a`? it's `1001011` instead of `75`.

Comment: You should be passing the number of characters to write to the function, and that's not `byte & 255`.

Comment: @chris, the instructions states I have to write the "least" significant byte to the ostream, which is why I had `byte & 255`

Comment: Using the flag `std::ios::binary` doesn't mean numeric literals are interpreted in binary - it switches off platform-specific line-end translation that's only appropriate for text files. The numeric literals don't know that they're being passed to stream-related functions.

Comment: @TokugawaIeysu, Which instructions? [This](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) says otherwise. That argument is the size of what you're writing.

Comment: @chris, the instructions to implement this method states that, and I thought I was writing to an ostream by passing in to the write method as an argument, the least significant byte of the method parameter

Comment: If all you want to write is the least significant byte of something, the second argument should be 1. The first is what data to write. Also note that endianness can affect your LSB calculation.

Comment: @chris, I apologize for my ignorance in understand the instructions, but when it says to "write the least significant byte of the argument to the ostream," doesnt that mean you take `byte` and bitwise AND it with 255 to get the least significant byte?...then pass that in as the argument to the write method?

Comment: @TokugawaIeysu, Yes, generally, but you assume the system is big-endian. A little-endian system would store your number "backwards". You also have to cast the data to a "byte array" (`const char *`) in order to pass it in as the first argument.

Answer (score 2):

this

```
writeObj.inByte(1001011);
```

calls the function with an integer = 1,001,001 decimal, not binary.

Comment: The header file contains an argument of type `int` for the `inByte` method. How do I test to make sure the method is indeed writing a byte of data to a file?

Comment: Pass a byte to it, not an int... Think separately from numbers and their (written) representation. 1001011 is a decimal representation (that it contains only 0s and 1s doesn't change this fact).

Comment: @leemes, I understand a number from its binary representation, but I'm not understanding what to pass into the parameter of the write function to write a byte to the file

Comment: Well, your source code has a particular representation. In this case, it's decimal. You want it to be binary. Once compiled, there is no "representation". The type of a byte is typically `char`. Set it to the correct decimal value of the byte you want to write. In your case it's `75` or in hexadecimal `0x4B`.

Comment: @leemes, so would I need to do something like `char *ptr = (char*)&byte` then pass `ptr` as the first argument of the write function?.....But then what do I pass it as the 2nd argument?

Comment: No, just use `char` (1 byte) instead of `int` (usually 4 bytes) for the number... Pass the *correct* number in the first place, don't convert something to a byte. Don't pass `1001011` (not one byte) but `75` (fits into one byte). I don't know how to explain any better... Sorry. Just don't interpret (you as a human being) `1001011` as a binary number, because the compiler won't do it either. It's a decimal  number and not what you want, because it doesn't fit in  one byte.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30006/discussion-between-tokugawa-ieysu-and-leemes)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use binary, consider `hex` or `std::bitset`

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 0x4B;    // 01001011
    bitset<8> bs(a);
    cout << hex << a << endl;
    cout << bs << endl;
}
```

if you output `std::bitset` to a file, every bit will be represented as a `char`, i.e., you will see `01001011` in you file.

Comment: Actually, `01001011` from binary to hex is `0x4B`